# DefaultValueAttribute conflicts with XML serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to let user modify an object before serializing it. For objects' editing I use PropertyGrid, so I have to add attributes to it like this:

```
    [CategoryAttribute("General"),
    DefaultValueAttribute(true),
    DescriptionAttribute("Calculate MD5")]
    public bool ComputeMd5 { get; set; }
```

When I try to serialize this object, property disappears, when I remove all properties, serialization goes through without any problems. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.
Apparently when you set Default Attribute and the actual value equals default serializer simply doesnt save it to file.